# Taxonomy Menu and Views don't work

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have vocab Categories, I created it as a menu with Taxonomy Menus. It lists terms in the sidebar, but when clicked on term, it opens empty page saying 'There is currently no content classified with this term.' I have term Hats & Visors, so path to it is shop/hats-visors/ and I expect it to show the list of hats content. These are my settings (screenshots): https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwqOW.jpg

And to the actual Hat content path is i.e. shop/hats-visors/hat aka /node/5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate content with that term.. To do that create a field term reference in content type.. And then edit your content and select term which you would like to associate with your content..

- Login as admin
- Navigate to list of content types "admin/structure/types"
- Choose content type using which your are creating content. Click on Manage Fields next to it.
- Add Term Reference field and choose Vocabulary Categories in settings
- Create Content or Edit your existing content to associate terms to content using above field you have created.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to add a screenshot to fields page, but the Term Reference field is already created and used with selected terms.